# Change Read more for multilanguage in wordpress

Tags: php, function, wordpress

Hello I have problem how to solve that read more change for German.
I use to change readmore in functions.php

```
function modify_read_more_link() {
    return '<a class="image-hover hvr-shutter-out-vertical button" href="' . get_permalink() . '">PROČITAJ</a>';
}

add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
```

how to change this when I use wpml plugin to translate PROČITAJ to MEHR.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try something like this

```
if ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='fr' ) { echo 'Bonjour'; }
elseif ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en' ) { echo 'Hello'; }
```